# Hudson email triger

Tags: email, triggers, hudson-plugins

I like to send email using hudson ext-email plugin, but with diferent triger than build status. I like to set hudson evn during buil or read it from env file (using env-file plugin) and depends of his value send email or not. How to do that?
BR.Marcin

Answer (score 1):

To conditionally send out an email based on an environment variable set in the build, you'll have to use a scripting language such as [Groovy](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Groovy+plugin).

Here's [an article](http://techkriti.wordpress.com/2008/08/30/using-groovy-with-hudson-to-send-rich-text-email/) discussing how to use a Groovy script inside Email-ext.